# dot product of a vector in a given direction

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

I have a vector field  $\vec A = (y^3+z^3)  \hat i + (x^3+z^3)  \hat j + (y^3+x^3)  \hat k$  defined over a unit sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

what is the magnitude of the component $\vec A$ normal to the spherical surface at the point $(1/\sqrt 3,1/\sqrt 3,1/\sqrt 3)$ ?

What i have done is, I have found the unit normal vector at the given point by parameterizing the sphere. then I found the dot product given vector field at the given point with the unit normal vector, which gave me a magnitude 0.66666

The actual answer is 1.333333

where did i go wrong?

Comment: $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ you mean ?

Comment: exactly. sorry for mistyping.

Answer (score 1):

The unit normal to the units sphere is just the coordinates to the given point on the sphere. So your dot product becomes:

\begin{align*}
 \vec A \cdot \vec n = 3((\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})^3+(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})^3)\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} = 6 (\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})^4 = \frac{6}{9} = \frac{2}{3}.
\end{align*}

So in short - you are right.

Comment: I have a doubt, why have you dotted with normal vector? It must be unit normal vector right? Having said that, in our case the normal vector is a unit normal vector. What if it's not?

Comment: If its not then you have to parameterization of the surface to calculate the unit normal. This case has some nice symmetries, and thus we may simplify the calculations a lot.

Comment: And yes it needs to be the unit normal. So I've edited my answer changing the word "normal" to "unit normal" which is  the correct thing ti say.